# How can I insert symbols on a map using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following issue which I believe is realisable via jquery, json or javascript.
I have a map with weather codes plotted (see attached map below. I would like to replace the codes with weather symbols recognisable to lay people, as the two symbols for rain and for wind I have included on the attached map.
The procedure would be to read the weather from a text file which contains the longtiude and latitude at which the symbol defined by the given weather type is to be displayed.

I would like assistance to a reference or references from which I can work, or if someone ahs a script which does similar work, I would appreciate.

The input data would be in the form:

```
Lon Lat Weather Stnid   Stnname
23.15   -15.25  Rain    67633   MONGU001
31.33    -8.85  windy   67413   MBALA001
...
```

![The symbols to be placed on a map like this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlpwH.jpg)

Assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: hard to help without knowing how the map is generated

Comment: I have been learning javascript, but not progressed much. Thank you very much @charlietfl, you raise a good point. My first task will be to generate a map. I will come back to this issue later when am done with a map.